# Method FindByLoginAsync doesn't work correctly with AspNetCore.Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I have used the `AspNetCore.Identity` in my Asp.Net Core application and I want to call the method called `FindByLoginAsync` but result is always NULL.

**Versions:**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (1.1.1)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (1.1.1)
```

**Code:**

```
var loginProvider = "Github"
var providerKey = "1234567";
var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(loginProvider, providerKey);
```

This record exists in the database, but this method returns always NULL.

I've tried trace the SQL query and I've got this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) [e].[ProviderKey], [e].[LoginProvider], [e].[ProviderDisplayName], [e].[UserId]
FROM [UserLogins] AS [e]
WHERE ([e].[ProviderKey] = @__get_Item_0) AND ([e].[LoginProvider] = @__get_Item_1)',N'@__get_Item_0 nvarchar(450),@__get_Item_1 nvarchar(450)',@__get_Item_0=N'Github',@__get_Item_1=N'1234567'
```

My SQL query is like `[e].[LoginProvider]` the value `providerKey`  and `[e].[ProviderKey]` the value `loginProvider`.

**Application DbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(i =>
            {
                i.ToTable("Users");
                i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });
            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(i =>
            {
                i.ToTable("Roles");
                i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>(i =>
            {
                i.ToTable("UserRoles");
                i.HasKey(x => new { x.RoleId, x.UserId });
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(i =>
            {
                i.ToTable("UserLogins");
                i.HasKey(x => new { x.ProviderKey, x.LoginProvider });
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>(i =>
            {
                i.ToTable("RoleClaims");
                i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>(i =>
            {
                i.ToTable("UserClaims");
                i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>(i =>
            {
                i.ToTable("UserTokens");
                i.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
            });
        }
    }
```

**Implementation of IdentityUser, IdentityRole**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{

}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
}
```

How can I fix this? How is this behaviour possible?

Comment: What is the result of that SQL query?

Comment: SQL query - nothing. :) Only if I change the paramaters in this method - like this: `var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(providerKey,loginProvider);`

Comment: I see, but the default implementation of `IdentityDbContext` use tables that begins with `AspNet`. In your SQL query, the table has name `UserLogins`. Are you using custom database context?

Comment: @laika I've updated my question, please take a look how I've implemented IdentityDbContext and IdentityUser, IdentityRole. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect order of primary keys in registration of entity `IdentityUserLogin`. Change it to this

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(i =>
{
    i.ToTable("UserLogins");
    i.HasKey(x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
});
```

That's the fix, now the rationale behind.

In version 1.1.1 the method [`UserStore.FindByLoginAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore.cs#L891) used method `DbSet.FindAsync`, which accepts ordered array of values for primary keys. The order must follow the order used in entity registration.

```
public async virtual Task<TUser> FindByLoginAsync(string loginProvider, string providerKey,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
   ...
   var userLogin = await UserLogins.FindAsync(new object[] { loginProvider, providerKey }, cancellationToken);
   ...
}
```

In the default implementation the primary keys are registered in [correct order](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs#L201)

```
builder.Entity<TUserLogin>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey });
    b.ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
});
```

Comment: You are right, that was the problem :) Thank you very much for your time and solve my issue. BTW: another configuration is okay?

Comment: @Jenan the `UserRole` has incorrect order too - first is `UserId`, then `RoleId`.. Besides that, it looks good.. If the answer had helped you, then please mark it as accepted.